# How do I select a specific item in a ComboBox?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have 2 items in a `ComboBox` which are "Eating In" and "Eating Out".

I want the program to add 20% VAT if the user selects "Eating In". If the user selects "Eating Out" I don't want any VAT adding.

I have the following code to work out my total which has worked successfully. I just need to find out how to assign the item in the `ComboBox` to add VAT.

```
dTotalCost = dTotalSandwichCost + dTotalDrinkCost + dTotalExtraCost
```

Comment: I don't think you want to select the specific item, you want to check which item is selected. Right? Have a look at the SelectedItem property of the combobox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possibility is to declare an Enum and calculate based on it. e.g.,
(Psuedocode, untested, just to give you an idea)

```
Enum AvailableEatingOptions
   EatingIn
   EatingOut
End Enum
```

then write like:

```
If comboBox.selectedIndex = AvailableEatingOptions.EatingIn Then
    dVAT = GivenVATValue * 0.2 ' Take 20% of your reference value
Else
    dVAT = 0
End If
```

then add this `dVAT` to your total.

[[Reference]](https://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-vbnet)